# how to add maya outliner to tabLayout

Tags: python, maya, autodesk, mel

I want to add maya outliner inside of the existing tabLayout

I came across a page that shows how to do it in MEL([the second method](http://mayastation.typepad.com/maya-station/2010/08/dockcontrol-part-2-adv-usage-1.html))

how would I do that in python ?

```
myOut= cmds.outlinerPanel()
cmds.control(edit=True,parent="outlinerLayout"  myOut)
```

the above gives syntax error, I guess I am doing it wrong in translating mel code to python code(i want in python coz the whole existing GUI app is done in python) and I want to implement the idea of having outliner tabbed into my project manager for the user removing the hassle of launching Outliner separately..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say it's a coma error:

```
myOut= cmds.outlinerPanel()
cmds.control(myOut, edit=True, parent="outlinerLayout")
```

Check out the Documentation:

[cmds.control](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/en_us/CommandsPython/index.html)

[cmds.outlinerPanel](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/en_us/CommandsPython/outlinerPanel.html)

Anyewy I would Highly suggest you to use [PyMel](http://autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/PyMel/index.html) instead of maya python, it's a better pythonic way to code in Maya. And also [PYQT4](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/) will make UI build up easier.

Comment: yes Daniel, it was comma error , and now I dont know why I get the outliner like this[link](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-75qqld3GrQA/UL8qd6ax8nI/AAAAAAAADeY/ALeeZBNrJtM/s512/theproblemo.PNG)

Comment: It sounds like it is not refreshing or something like that, could you please show me some more code? Look for a PYQT4 change in your code if it is not too much developed already, I think it will speed up things.

Comment: I am new to PyQt4 and not much familiar with it so as of now Command module is all i have for GUI, atm I am looking for learning resources for PyQt4 for maya instead of making a QApplication...

Comment: now that the outliner shows in the beginning but when i open new scene it is not their iin the second outliner tab and when i query it it turs out to be false , what is makeing its existance to be false and how should i show it up again ?